How do I properly implement MailMergeAfterRecordMerge for a macro I put together?
My mail merge .docm + .xlsx document connection works fine, and my macro runs fine when manually run from the VBA editor. However, I can not get it to run per mail merge record...
I am using Microsoft Office 2013.
This is what I am specifically trying to implement:
Application.MailMergeAfterRecordMerge event (Word)
The entirety of my test code is as follows. I am sure I am missing some things, so please specify exactly what and exactly where so I can get this example code Microsoft provides working.
I am posting my current code and screenshots to clarify where I am stuck at.
My goal is to get my sub procedure "MakeStuffHappen" to run after each record merge to fill in the DocVariable fileds, so when the mailmerge is printed all the desired data is on the page.
Project (TestingVBA) → Microsoft Word Objects → ThisDocument
Public WithEvents myApp As Word.Application
Public myDoc As Document
Public myMerge As MailMerge
Public myField As MailMergeDataField
Public myFields As MailMergeDataFields
Public myFieldName As MailMergeFieldName
Public myFieldNames As MailMergeFieldNames
Public mySource As MailMergeDataSource

Function chkArray(myArray, myItem)

chkArray = False

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    If myArray(i) = myItem Then
        chkArray = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function

Sub MakeStuffHappen()

Set myApp = Application
Set myDoc = myApp.ActiveDocument
Set myMerge = myDoc.MailMerge
Set myFields = myMerge.DataSource.DataFields

Dim myProduct As String

myProduct = myFields("PRODUCT").Value

Dim grp1, grp2, grp3 As Variant

grp1 = Array("APPLE", "ORANGE", "PEAR", "PEACH", "TANGERINE")
grp2 = Array("VODKA", "GIN", "WHISKY", "BOURBON")
grp3 = Array("WALNUT", "PECAN", "ALMOND", "CASHEW", "PEANUT", "HAZELNUT")

Dim test1, test2, test3 As Boolean

test1 = chkArray(grp1, myProduct)
test2 = chkArray(grp2, myProduct)
test3 = chkArray(grp3, myProduct)

Dim priceGrp As Currency, grpArray As Variant, grpName As String

If test1 = True Then
    grpArray = grp1
    grpName = "Fruits"
    priceGrp = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Fruit_Price").Range
ElseIf test2 = True Then
    grpArray = grp2
    grpName = "Liquors"
    priceGrp = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Liquor_Price").Range
ElseIf test3 = True Then
    grpArray = grp3
    grpName = "Nuts"
    priceGrp = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Nut_Price").Range
End If

Dim startDate As Date, timespan As Integer, endDate As Date

startDate = myFields("START_DATE").Value
timespan = myFields("YEARS").Value
endDate = DateAdd("yyyy", timespan, startDate)

Dim fullPrice, payMe1, payMe2 As Variant

If timespan = 1 Then
    fullPrice = priceGrp * 0.5 + 25
    payMe1 = fullPrice
    payMe2 = ""
ElseIf timespan = 2 Then
    fullPrice = priceGrp
    payMe2 = fullPrice * 0.5
    payMe1 = payMe2 + 25

ElseIf timespan = 0 Then
    fullPrice = ""
    payMe1 = ""
    payMe2 = ""
End If

ActiveDocument.Variables("END_DATE").Value = Format(endDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
ActiveDocument.Variables("PRICE").Value = "$" + Format(fullPrice, "#0.00")
ActiveDocument.Variables("PAY1").Value = "$" + Format(payMe1, "#0.00")
ActiveDocument.Variables("PAY2").Value = "$" + Format(payMe2, "#0.00")
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

Debug.Print Chr(34) + myProduct + Chr(34) + " is part of " + Chr(34) + grpName + Chr(34) + " (" + Join(grpArray, ", ") + ")"
Debug.Print "Price is $" + CStr(priceGrp)
Debug.Print "Start Date is " + Format(startDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Debug.Print "duration is: " + CStr(timespan) + " year(s)"
Debug.Print "end date: " + Format(endDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Debug.Print "Price: $" + Format(fullPrice, "#0.00")
Debug.Print "Payment #1 is: $" + Format(payMe1, "#0.00")
Debug.Print "Payment #2 is: $" + Format(payMe2, "#0.00")

End Sub

Project (TestingVBA) → Modules → AutoOpen
Sub ConnectToSpreadsheet()
'
' ConnectToSpreadsheet Macro created by the Record Macro Wizard, renamed the Module to AutoOpen so it fires when document opens

    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:="C:\VBAstuff\testList.xlsx", _
         ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", _
        WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
        Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:= _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\VBAstuff\testList.xlsx;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OL" _
        , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `CUSTOMERS$`", SQLStatement1:="", SubType _
        :=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
End Sub

Screenshot

Project (TestingVBA) → Modules → AutoOpen
remains unchanged, so the .xlsx file is auto loaded and mailmerge process initialized.
All other code in "ThisDocument" is commented out for testing purposes the entirety of ThisDocument is listed next.
Project (TestingVBA) → Microsoft Word Objects → ThisDocument
Public WithEvents MailMergeApp As Word.Application

Private Sub MailMergeApp_MailMergeAfterRecordMerge(ByVal Doc As Document)

    With Doc.MailMerge.DataSource
        MsgBox .DataFields("FIRST_NAME").Value & " " & .DataFields("LAST_NAME").Value & " is the current record being merged."
    End With

End Sub

Dim X As EventClassModule

Sub DoTheMerge()
    Set X = New EventClassModule
    Set X.MailMergeApp = Word.Application
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .Execute
    End With
    Set X.MailMergeApp = Nothing
    Set X = Nothing
End Sub

Project (TestingVBA) → Class Modules → EventClassModule
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Dim X As New EventClassModule
Sub Register_Event_Handler()
    Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub


The smallest connection string I could make work and not give a compile error:
Sub AutoOpen()

    ' Procedure to connect to the xlsx data source

    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
    Name:="C:\VBAstuff\testList.xlsx", _
    Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\VBAstuff\testList.xlsx;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OL", _
    SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `CUSTOMERS$`"

End Sub


I've edited this Answer to try to create a working piece of code with as little change from your original code as I can manage (more or less).
I've left my original answer at the end.
First, using the AfterRecordMerge Event isn't going to work IMO, because by the time Word executes that event code, it has already created the Form Letter, and during that process will have discarded bookmarks and replaced as many fields as it can, including MERGEFIELD fields and DOCVARIABLE fields by their values at the time it generated the Letter. So you really have to work out the values of the DOCVARIABLEs before Word creates the letter.
Put this in an ordinary Module (or in ThisDocument, if you like). NB it's the Sub that needs to be called AutoOpen if you want it to execute automatically.
Sub AutoOpen()
'
' This Macro created by the Record Macro Wizard, renamed the Module to AutoOpen so it fires when document opens
'
'
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _      
  Name:="C\VBAstuff\testList.xlsx", _
  ConfirmConversions:=False, _
  ReadOnly:=False, _
  LinkToSource:=True, _
  AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
  PasswordDocument:="", _
  PasswordTemplate:="", _
  WritePasswordDocument:="", _
  WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
  Revert:=False, _
  Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
  Connection:= _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\VBAstuff\testList.xlsx;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OL",  _
  SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `CUSTOMERS$`", _
  SQLStatement1:="", _
  SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
End Sub

Put the following code in a Class Module called EventClassModule. The Event code has to be in a Class Module. As it stands this code could be improved in a variety of ways but it does at least function.
Public WithEvents MailMergeApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Document
Public myMerge As MailMerge
Dim myField As MailMergeDataField
Dim myFields As MailMergeDataFields
Dim myFieldName As MailMergeFieldName
Dim myFieldNames As MailMergeFieldNames
Dim mySource As MailMergeDataSource

Dim grp1, grp2, grp3 As Variant

Public Sub init()
  Set MailMergeApp = Word.Application
  Set myDoc = MailMergeApp.ActiveDocument
  Set myMerge = myDoc.MailMerge
  Set myFields = myMerge.DataSource.DataFields
  grp1 = Array("APPLE", "ORANGE", "PEAR", "PEACH", "TANGERINE")
  grp2 = Array("VODKA", "GIN", "WHISKY", "BOURBON")
  grp3 = Array("WALNUT", "PECAN", "ALMOND", "CASHEW", "PEANUT", "HAZELNUT")
End Sub

Public Sub cleanup()
  Set myDoc = Nothing
  Set myMerge = Nothing
  Set myFields = Nothing
  Set MailMergeApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function chkArray(myArray, myItem)

chkArray = False

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    If myArray(i) = myItem Then
        chkArray = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function

Sub MakeStuffHappen()

Dim myProduct As String

myProduct = myFields("PRODUCT").Value


Dim test1, test2, test3 As Boolean

test1 = chkArray(grp1, myProduct)
test2 = chkArray(grp2, myProduct)
test3 = chkArray(grp3, myProduct)

Dim priceGrp As Currency, grpArray As Variant, grpName As String

If test1 = True Then
    grpArray = grp1
    grpName = "Fruits"
    priceGrp = myDoc.Bookmarks("Fruit_Price").Range
ElseIf test2 = True Then
    grpArray = grp2
    grpName = "Liquors"
    priceGrp = myDoc.Bookmarks("Liquor_Price").Range
ElseIf test3 = True Then
    grpArray = grp3
    grpName = "Nuts"
    priceGrp = myDoc.Bookmarks("Nut_Price").Range
End If

Dim startDate As Date, timespan As Integer, endDate As Date

startDate = myFields("START_DATE").Value
timespan = myFields("YEARS").Value
endDate = DateAdd("yyyy", timespan, startDate)

Dim fullPrice, payMe1, payMe2 As Variant

If timespan = 1 Then
    fullPrice = priceGrp * 0.5 + 25
    payMe1 = fullPrice
    payMe2 = ""
ElseIf timespan = 2 Then
    fullPrice = priceGrp
    payMe2 = fullPrice * 0.5
    payMe1 = payMe2 + 25

ElseIf timespan = 0 Then
    fullPrice = ""
    payMe1 = ""
    payMe2 = ""
End If

myDoc.Variables("END_DATE").Value = Format(endDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
myDoc.Variables("PRICE").Value = "$" + Format(fullPrice, "#0.00")
myDoc.Variables("PAY1").Value = "$" + Format(payMe1, "#0.00")
myDoc.Variables("PAY2").Value = "$" + Format(payMe2, "#0.00")
myDoc.Fields.Update

Debug.Print Chr(34) + myProduct + Chr(34) + " is part of " + Chr(34) + grpName + Chr(34) + " (" + Join(grpArray, ", ") + ")"
Debug.Print "Price is $" + CStr(priceGrp)
Debug.Print "Start Date is " + Format(startDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Debug.Print "duration is: " + CStr(timespan) + " year(s)"
Debug.Print "end date: " + Format(endDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Debug.Print "Price: $" + Format(fullPrice, "#0.00")
Debug.Print "Payment #1 is: $" + Format(payMe1, "#0.00")
Debug.Print "Payment #2 is: $" + Format(payMe2, "#0.00")

End Sub

Private Sub MailMergeApp_MailMergeBeforeRecordMerge(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
With Doc.MailMerge.DataSource
Call MakeStuffHappen
'MsgBox .DataFields("FIRST_NAME").Value & " " & .DataFields("LAST_NAME").Value & " is merged."
End With

End Sub

Put the following code in either ThisDocument or an ordinary (not Class) Module. This is the code that needs to run when the User is ready to do the merge.(So you may need to assign a keystroke or some such so that the User can run it.
Dim X As EventClassModule

Sub dothemerge()
Set X = New EventClassModule
Call X.init
With X.myMerge
  .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
  .Execute
End With
Call X.cleanup
Set X = Nothing
End Sub

Just as an observation, Word currently records a lot more code than you actually need for an Excel connection. The following will probably be enough:
Sub AutoOpen()
'
' This Macro created by the Record Macro Wizard, renamed the Module to AutoOpen so it fires when document opens
'
'
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _      
  Name:="C\VBAstuff\testList.xlsx", _
  SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `CUSTOMERS$`"
End Sub

[Below is the original answer+edits]
The document's Events need to be enabled before the Mail Merge Events will "fire" during a merge.
To achieve that, you need more than the code that you posted in your question, as indicated by the remark under Syntax in the article you referenced : "For information about using events with the Application object, see Using events with the Application object."
I suggest you do this to get your code working, then restructure as necessary, skipping any steps that you have already done.
Save your mail merge main document as a macro-enabled document (.docm)
Use Insert->Class Module to insert a class module in that document.
Use the VB Editor's Properties Pane to rename the module to EventCLassModule.
(You will also need to ensure that there are quotation marks around LAST_NAME in your code).
In the document's THisDocument module, put the following code
Dim X As EventClassModule

Sub DoTheMerge()
Set X = New EventClassModule
Set X.MailMergeApp = Word.Application
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
  .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
  .Execute
End With
Set X.MailMergeApp = Nothing
Set X = Nothing
End Sub

Ensure that your document is the activedocument (it won't be after you have successfully completed a Merge), then run DoTheMerge.
If you just want to enable the events, you can do that by adding the following code to ThisDocument
Sub EnableMergeEvents()
Set X = New EventClassModule
Set X.MailMergeApp = Word.Application
End Sub

Then, when you go through the "Finish & Merge" option in the ribbon, the merge should be done with events firing. Then you would need to disable the eventts, e.g. using
Sub DisableMergeEvents()
Set X.MailMergeApp = Nothing
Set X = Nothing
End Sub

Just be aware that when you enable events in this way, they will (probably) be enabled for any merge (not just this document) and some actions may result in the events being disabled (I forget off the top of my head, but e.g. changing one of the event routines might cause that).
Not actually relevant to your question but something to be aware of if you need to deal with text fields over 255 characters long ("memo" fields) is that Word may merge them correctly, but doc.Mailmerge.DataFields("NameOfTheMemoField") only returns the first 255 characters.
